# Qt - start process with click event and stop it again with the second click event

Tags: qt

I found time to investigate a bit into QT, and it is very interesting for me. However, right now I am encountering a problem that I am not aware about how to solve it. My aim is actually simple. I have a `QCheckBox` that I want to activate. If it is activated, I am starting a process (I am opening a file, reading it, taking some values out and change different labels accordingly). This process is repeated until the user is deactivating the `QCheckBox`. Some small code example to get a better idea of what I am going to do.

```
void Analyzer::on_actualTemperature_stateChanged(int arg1)
{
   // Read data and change labels
   if (arg1 != 0)
   {
       qDebug() << "Start data analysis";

       // Infinity loop to get the data and display it
       while true
       {
           // Open file and extract data
           const actualTemperature = getData();

           // Change any label or do something with the data
           ui->anyLabel->setText(actualTemperature);

           // Some break
           QThread::sleep(1);

           // Leave the loop if user deactivate the QCheckBox
           // Something like on_actualTemperature_stateChange == 0 
       }
   }
   // Stop reading the data
   else
   {
       qDebug() << "Stop data analysis";
   }
}
```

It is obvious that after activating the `QCheckBox`, the loop will not finish at all and the GUI will not recognize anything anymore. Hence, I guess I have to start some new thread and have to kill it. However, I have no idea how to proceed here. An idea would be:

```
void Analyzer::on_actualTemperature_stateChanged(int arg1)
{
   // Read data and change labels
   if (arg1 != 0)
   {
       // Start reading the file and updating the label using some other thread
       startThread(XY);
   }
   // Stop reading the data
   else
   {
       // Kill thread 1234
       killThread(XY);
   }
}
```

Any hint is warmly welcomed and I hope this question is not too basic for you. Thank you for reading, Tobi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think killing a running thread is not a decent behavior. Let's be gentle to our threads with a loop control variable. In this example it named `keepLoop`. Set `keepLoop` when checkbox checked. Then start thread if it is not running. We are using [QtConcurrent::run](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html), and monitoring it by a [QFuture](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html) in this case.

```
connect(ui->checkBox, &QCheckBox::toggled, 
    [&](const bool checked) {
        analyzer->keepLoop = checked;
        if (checked && !future.isRunning())
            future = QtConcurrent::run(analyzer, &Analyzer::on_actualTemperature_stateChanged);
    }
);
```

Don't call user interface slots directly, instead connect them to signals. Connections will be queued connection when signals emitted from another thread. It means slots will be called in event loop of main thread and changes will be shown when the next frame painted.

```
connect(analyzer, &Analyzer::temperatureCalculated, ui->anyLabel, &QLabel::setText);
```

Our asynchronous function does not forced to die immediately when user toggle checkbox. Instead we letting it to finish the iteration it already on halfway through.

```
Analyzer::on_actualTemperature_stateChanged() {
    while (keepLoop) {
        // Open file and extract data
        const QString& actualTemperature = getData();

        // send data
        emit temperatureCalculated(actualTemperature);
    }
}
```

You can use atomic bool if you want a more precise loop control.

Bonus:
If you don't want to mess with threads, you can avoid GUI freezing by using [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) to run your loop periodically in main thread.

Comment: Thank you very much Kao. I agree that killing a thread is not a good way :)... I will check out the method you described and also the connection regarding slots and signals. I am new to qt and hence, I have to learn a lot.

Comment: Just a quick question. What is `analyzer` in your code? Its a pointer to which object class? I guess the `analyzer->checked` is simply a private/public boolean object from the `Analyzer` class, as in the last part you directly call the object within the `while (keepLoop)` Will check it.

Comment: @Tobi `analyzer` is `Analyzer*`. I assumed `Analyzer` as a logic class that inherits `QObject` and lives in your ui class(QWidget). `Analyzer` has a member `bool keepLoop` and signal `void temperatureCalculated(QString)` and functions like `on_actualTemperature_stateChanged()`. Connections are made in UI class, probably in constructor.

Comment: you can also put `QFuture future` in analyzer as member to provide a async function like `void async_on_actualTemperature_stateChanged() { 
if (!future.isRunning()) 
future = QtConcurrent::run(this, &Analyzer::on_actualTemperature_stateChanged); }`.

Comment: thank you for all your hints. I got the idea how to do it but I have problems with the `connect` function. The `Analyzer` is similar to the `MainWindow` class and includes `QMainWindow`. I will need to start simpler. Thank you.

Comment: works now ... thank you very much. Now I got everything you mentioned. :) Perfect.